# What is net interface 'vip0'?

Tags: networking

When I list network devices on my Android phone, I see vip0 in the list and this is bugging me.

I can't find any information relating to this mystery device.

Can anyone possibly tell me what this device is used for?

Comment: Looks like a VPN tunnel to me...

Comment: As the starter, it seems like it's a [virtual IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_IP_address). However, I don't know much about network interface.